# Перегрузка метода RegisterDecorator из namespace Autofac

Tags: c#, autofac

Есть такой код

```
builder.RegisterType<ReportingService>().Named<IReportingService>("reporting"); 
builder.RegisterDecorator<IReportingService>((context, service) => new ReportingServiceWithLogging(service), "reporting");
```

ВОПРОС: скажите пожалста какая перегрузка метода тут использована взятого [отсюда](https://autofac.org/apidoc/html/8AE84CD9.htm) и по чем это видно ?

Comment: Ваши вопросы очень странные и яб даже сказал, вредные для SO, ибо они низкого качества... Ну ведь сами можете подумать немного и понять что и как вызывается. Вот переходит по ссылке, открываем первый метод, видим `this ContainerBuilder builder, Func<IDecoratorContext, bool> condition = nul` - подходит? Нет, ибо у вас еще строковой "ключ", открываем следующий, видим там также не ту сигнатуру метода, которая у вас, открываем 3-й вариант, также не ваш (ибо вы просите `context` и `service`, а там возвращается только последнее. Открываем 4-ую и о чудо, все совпадает. Ну ведь элементарно...

Comment: Вот нашел на SO вопрос на эту же тему - "Method Signature in C#". . . просмотров в сотни раз больше за 12 лет . . . но никто не нашел эту тему вреднющей . . . однако, я вам благодарен за пояснение

Comment: Если вы [про этот](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8808703/6808809) вопрос, то там не спрашивается "что это за метод и от куда он, там спрашивается "возвращаемый тип относится к сигнатуре метода", что является вполне нормальным вопросом на конкретную тему. Вы-же в свою очередь публикуете вопросы **бесполезные** для других людей, ибо если у человека не будет вашего кода, то вопрос "какой метод вызывается" теряет вообще какую либо актуальность. Помните, SO это **база полезных вопросов**, которые полезны не только вам (автору), но и будущим читателям.

Comment: Лично я получив ответ на свой вопрос закрыл для себя тему соответствия всех возможных сигнатур, вроде как . . . поэтому полезность темы для меня очевидна. Остальные читатели знают что сигнатура - присуща наверное всем методам - а не только тем что в созданной мной теме. Если что не так - на странице всегда есть кнопочка "Тревога", нажав на которую наверное можно начать процедуру удаления темы

Comment: Я вас лишь прошу уделять поиску нужной информации **больше** времени и уважать **сообщество** в котором находитесь. Как видите, я вам даже минуса не поставил, а вы о тревогах вдруг заговорили... Хотите поспорить на эту тему, узнать мнение сообщества - задайте вопрос на мете, будем обсуждать. Ну а пока, я лишь высказал свое мнение, не более, имею я ведь право считать ваши вопросы "вредными", да? Имею, как и вы имеете право их задавать. Что касается enSO, попробуйте задать там этот вопрос, что-то мне кажется, вы очень быстро наловите уйму минусов. На этом диалог думаю стоит завершить.